# Curl GET request is returning a JSON object, along with a string of the same object

Tags: php, curl, axios

I have a GET request on my server that I am requesting from the client-side.

**Client**

```
    axios({
      method: 'GET',
      url: {url},
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    }).then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data);

    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    })
```

**Server**

```
    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, [
      CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.rechargeapps.com/selling_plan_groups/',
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 50,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'X-Recharge-Access-Token: $token
      ],
    ]);

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    $allowed_origins = [
// origins
    ];

    if(in_array($request->get_header('origin'), $allowed_origins)) {
      header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$request->get_header('origin')}");
    }

    if ($err) {
      echo 'cURL Error #:' . $err;
    } else {
      echo $response;
    }
    return $response;
```

My issue is that the response from the server includes the JSON, followed by a string of data, and has made trying to parse the JSON very hacky. I have been able to make this request in node.js and receive just the JSON object as expected. Is there something else I can include in my PHP to prevent the second string from returning?

**Data Returned**
[How data is returned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDVcm.png)

Comment: I image because you `echo $response; return $response;`. Have you tired not echoing it?

Comment: @Justinas thank you for pointing that out, the issue is resolved. I appreciate the extra set of eyes!!